# MySQL Could Not Process Parameters

Tags: python, mysql

So I have data in a 2 Dimensional Array, and I am trying to insert it into my SQL Database.

```
for scrapeddata in range(len(all_images)):
    mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM ScrapedBooks WHERE BookLink = %s',( all_images[scrapeddata][3],))
    img_link_table = mycursor.fetchall()
    if len(img_link_table)==0:
        HoldBookTitle = [all_images[scrapeddata][0], all_images[scrapeddata][2],all_images[scrapeddata][1],all_images[scrapeddata][3]]

        mycursor.executemany("INSERT INTO ScrapedBooks(BookName, Price, ImageLink, BookLink) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)", (HoldBookTitle))
        mydb.commit()
```

Error:

```
mycursor.executemany("INSERT INTO ScrapedBooks(BookName, Price, ImageLink, BookLink) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)", (HoldBookTitle))

File"C:\Users\msala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 355, in executemany
    stmt = self._batch_insert(operation, seq_params)

  File "C:\Users\msala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 333, in _batch_insert
    raise errors.InterfaceError(

mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters
```

I plan to use the saved data in the database in my HTML code for my website, if you guys have any idea on how to do that, please do help me. Thank you!

Comment: don't use parenthesis around an array

Comment: Still no luck, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Array can't be handled that way, but you can make an array of lists and add that ion one go into the database

```
all_images = []
HoldBookTitle = []

for scrapeddata in range(len(all_images)):
    mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM ScrapedBooks WHERE BookLink = %s',( all_images[scrapeddata][3],))
    img_link_table = mycursor.fetchall()
    if len(img_link_table)>0:
        HoldBookTitle.append( (all_images[scrapeddata][0], all_images[scrapeddata][2],all_images[scrapeddata][1],all_images[scrapeddata][3]))
if not HoldBookTitle:
    mycursor.executemany("INSERT INTO ScrapedBooks(BookName, Price, ImageLink, BookLink) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)", HoldBookTitle)
    mydb.commit()
```

Comment: you the best, thank you!